# Using this.refs is deprecated error when trying to use this.refs.value

Tags: node.js, reactjs, compiler-errors, loopbackjs, ref

II am trying to do a post request to the database to post an object called questions using `"react-dom": "^15.6.1"`. The data might be something as follows:

```
{description: 'What is E-commerce?', ismeeting: false, expID: '123A2'}
```

What i am trying to do is take the "description" , "ismeeting" and ,"expID" values from a form and a checkbox (checkbox for "ismeeting") in the front end and pass it to the backend. To get the description value for instance; i am using `this.refs.description.value`. However i am getting an error `Using this.refs is deprecated` in the onSubmit(e) function and `Using string literals in ref attributes is deprecated  react/no-string-refs` in the render() function

Here is the **OnSubmit code**.

```
     onSubmit(e) {
    const newQues = {
      description: this.refs.description.value,
      ismeeting: this.refs.check_me.checked,
      expID: this.refs.expID.value
    };
    this.addQues(newQues);
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

and here is the **render() code**.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <br/>
        <h1> DO NOT HESISTATE TO ASK OUR EXPERTS </h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <div className="input-field">
            <input type="text" name="description" ref="description"/>
            <label htmlFor="description"> Description </label>
          </div>
          <div className="input-field">
            <input type="text" name="expID" ref="expID"/>
            <label htmlFor="name"> expID </label>
          </div>
          <div className="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="ismeeting" ref="check_me" />Meeting
            </label>
          </div>
          <input type ="submit" value="ASK" className="btn" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**finally this is the full code**.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../Styles.scss';

class Questions extends Component {
  addQues(newQues) {
    console.log(newQues);
    axios.request({
      method: 'Post',
      url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/Questions',
      data: newQues
    }).then(response => {
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      Questions: []
    };
  }
  onSubmit(e) {
    const newQues = {
      description: this.refs.description.value,
      ismeeting: this.refs.check_me.checked,
      expID: this.refs.expID.value
    };
    this.addQues(newQues);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <br/>
        <h1> DO NOT HESISTATE TO ASK OUR EXPERTS </h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <div className="input-field">
            <input type="text" name="description" ref="description"/>
            <label htmlFor="description"> Description </label>
          </div>
          <div className="input-field">
            <input type="text" name="expID" ref="expID"/>
            <label htmlFor="name"> expID </label>
          </div>
          <div className="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="ismeeting" ref="check_me" />Meeting
            </label>
          </div>
          <input type ="submit" value="ASK" className="btn" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Questions;
```

Answer (score 0):

String refs have been deprecated. So what you need to do is update your refs

`<input type="text" name="expID" ref="expID"/>`

should be updated to

```
setExpIdRef = (r) => this.expIdRef = r;


onSubmit = (e) => {
  const newQues = {
    expID: this.expIdRef.value
  };
  // Do what you need to with newQuest i.e call your database
}

render() {
  ...
  <input type="text" name="expID" ref={this.setExpIdRef}/>
}
```

The best solution is to make your inputs **controlled** inputs. Where you keep track of the value in the state.

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    expID: ''
  };
}

onExpIdChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({ 
    expID: e.target.value
  })
}

onSubmit = (e) => {
  const newQues = {
    expID: this.state.expID
  };
  // Do what you need with the newQues object
}

render() {
  ...
  <input type="text" name="expID" onChange={this.onExpIdChange} />
}
```

Comment: But where is the part where i pass the "Question" object to the database in the OnSubmit?

Comment: I added pseudocode to show what you need to do to handle removing the deprecation warnings. You can use the `newQues` object and do what you need to with it in the onSubmit